# Let CompareTo() convert to the type it's being compared to

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
if (value is decimal)
{
    if ((value as IComparable)?.CompareTo(0m) > 0)
        return Task.FromResult(PreconditionResult.FromSuccess());
}

if (value is int)
{
    if ((value as IComparable)?.CompareTo(0) > 0)
        return Task.FromResult(PreconditionResult.FromSuccess());
}
```

I have the following piece of code, here I have two if statements that check if `value` which is actually of the type `object` is a decimal or int. But I feel like I'm writing double code here, how I can make the `CompareTo()` method automatically convert the type it receives to the type it's compared to?

Comment: You can try to use `Comparer<T>.Default;` for that

Comment: `if ((value as IComparable)?.CompareTo(0m) > 0)` problem is here. Assume value is an `int` and I compare it to `0m` or vice versa it errors.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski could you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

My fix is to always convert it to Decimal in order to see if `value` is greater than 0.

```
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(value) > 0m)
            return Task.FromResult(PreconditionResult.FromSuccess());
```

Comment: This doesn’t work if `value` is zero-valued because `Convert.ToDecimal` doesn’t return failure information,

Comment: @Dai what would you suggest?

Comment: Use `if( value is Decimal decValue ) { ... }`.